# MVC/Web API add controller models and context dropdown

Tags: entity-framework, model, controller, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api project, inside that project I have referenced a previous project (a DLL, not the project itself) that I want to contain my Models and DbContexts.

When adding a controller to the Web Api project using the "wizard" for "add a web api 2 controller using entity framework", I want the referenced projects models and contexts to be populated in the model and context drop down lists. Is this possible? If so, HOW?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, I've just tried exactly that in VS 2013 and they appear no problem. If you can see them try typing the name of class or context.

**UPDATE**

Make sure the classes are public. Make sure the project is referenced. Make sure all projects are built/compiled. You need to add more detail of your project structure and the version of VS you are using if none of these help.

Comment: Does the imported dll have to follow some sort of folder naming convention in order for the main project's add controller "wizard" to display them? If not then what ideas can you give as suspicion for why they don't display for me